# Java execute() vs executeUpdate() to refresh materialized view in Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I was trying to refresh materialized views in Postgresql from my Java program:

```
conn = AbstractClientDao.getJdbcConnection();
pst = conn.prepareStatement("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_my_materialized_view;");
pst.execute();
conn.close();
```

As per the documentation, the execute() method can be used on any kind of SQL statement:

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, **which may be any kind of SQL statement**.

Note: I don't need to know about the result in this part of the program, so the return value is not important.

This code **is not doing anything** in the database, the materialized view is not updated but no error/exception is thrown in the java program.
After looking around a bit I went with the same code but using **executeUpdate()**:

```
conn = AbstractClientDao.getJdbcConnection();
pst = conn.prepareStatement("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_my_materialized_view;");
pst.executeUpdate();
conn.close();
```

From the documentation, the executeUpdate() also work on any kind of SQL:

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

This code **is working** and correctly updates the view.

Am I missing something or the documentation is not clear enough about the differences betweend *execute()* and *executeUpdate()* ?

Note: Java8, Postgresql 9.6, Driver org.postgresql, version 9.3-1101-jdbc41

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue. Adding WITH DATA at the end of materialized view creation script was my problem.

> PostgreSQL

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_mat_view
AS
SELECT * FROM my_table
WITH DATA
;
```

> JAVA

```
entityManager
.createNativeQuery("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_mat_view;")
.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** There is no difference between the 2 versions of this code. My problem was due to race conditions in my database.